# Element inspector not working (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, debugging

When I am clicking "Show inspector" in debug menu and then select any element, the info about it is not shown

[image]

I tried to use react-devtools, but it is not connecting for some reason

[image]

I made a reload, it started working again, and after one more reload stopped working...

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the inspector was in the collapsed mode because the react-dev tools were opened. When I closed the react-dev-tools the inspector on the iPhone simulator is seen as I expected.

I found the solution for my case from the React Native documentation.

> However, when react-devtools is running, Inspector will enter a collapsed mode, and instead use the DevTools as primary UI.

For more information:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#integration-with-react-native-inspector

[image]

Comment: In my case it happened when I had Flipper running, because it runs react-dev-tools too!

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented on react-devtools v4.
https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/496#issuecomment-623867308